# И-ый клик удаления блока

Tags: javascript

Как сделать многоповторное удаления блок 
Есть два разных блока хочу чтобы при клике item-блок удалялся именно тот на который кликнул

```js
var close=document.getElementById('close');
var f=document.querySelector('.feedback__mes');

this.close.addEventListener('click', function() {
 f.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
.feedback__wrapper {
 display: flex;
 
 max-width: 1100px;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 2px solid #eee;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;

}

.feedback__mes>.title {
 color: #EB2326;
}

.feedback__mes {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.feedback__wrapper h1 {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="feedback__wrapper">
                      <div class="red" style="width: 4px; height: auto; background-color: red;"></div>
                      <div class="feedback__mes">
                        <h2 class="title">Pull&Bear</h2>
                        <p>Здравствуйте! Друзья, хочу вас всех призвать к ультиматуму руководства нашего ТЦ, заплатить полную стоимость аренда за прошедший месяц просто-напросто не…
                        <img src="img/close.svg" alt="img" id="close">
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.feedback__wrapper');

blocks.forEach(block => {
  const closeButton = block.querySelector('.close');
  closeButton.onclick = e => e.target.closest('.feedback__wrapper').remove();
});
```

```css
.feedback__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  margin: 10px;
}

.feedback__mes>.title {
  color: #EB2326;
}

.feedback__mes {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.feedback__wrapper h1 {
  color: red;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback__wrapper">
  <div class="red" style="width: 4px; height: auto; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="feedback__mes">
    <h2 class="title">Pull&Bear [1]</h2>
    <p>Здравствуйте! Друзья, хочу вас всех призвать к ультиматуму руководства нашего ТЦ, заплатить полную стоимость аренда за прошедший месяц просто-напросто не…
      <i class="close">&#9746;</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="feedback__wrapper">
  <div class="red" style="width: 4px; height: auto; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="feedback__mes">
    <h2 class="title">Pull&Bear [2]</h2>
    <p>Здравствуйте! Друзья, хочу вас всех призвать к ультиматуму руководства нашего ТЦ, заплатить полную стоимость аренда за прошедший месяц просто-напросто не…
      <i class="close">&#9746;</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="feedback__wrapper">
  <div class="red" style="width: 4px; height: auto; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="feedback__mes">
    <h2 class="title">Pull&Bear [3]</h2>
    <p>Здравствуйте! Друзья, хочу вас всех призвать к ультиматуму руководства нашего ТЦ, заплатить полную стоимость аренда за прошедший месяц просто-напросто не…
      <i class="close">&#9746;</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если клик всегда идет по close-картинке, которая одноуровнего вложена в контейнер, что нужно удалить, тогда можно получить ссылку на этот контейнер через `event.target.parentNode`. Ему и выдать `display: none`.
А руководство ТЦ жалко...(

Comment: Будет несколько таких блоков и нужно делать не один клик по удалению

Comment: В event.target.parentNode, если у вас у каждого такого блока будет такая же структура, что и в приложенном коде, всегда будет хранится ссылка именно и только на тот блок, в котором вы кликнули по close-картинке.